# How to notify high load and low load using NGINX

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, autoscaling

Is it possible to be notified by calling an API through **NGINX** when the load is very high depending upon the threshold that is configured as well as during the server sitting idle with much less load.

My intention is to build a service that will be called during this to **horizontally** `scale up` the system and `scale down` whenever necessary .

Thank you for your reply in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best to scale depending on the actual cpu/ram or eth load because you could have an high load on nginx but still your server could be running smoothly.

You could use [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) or similar.